# A Semi-Independent Chapter (of an organization)

Tags: phrase-requests, business-language

I have a chapter of an organization that would like to position itself as less strongly affiliated with the parent organization. They want to be under the umbrella but not as consolidated as full chapters are. Less guidance, less on message, less formality. Guesses on what they should call themselves? I'm looking for something like a semi-independent chapter.

Comment: "Less strongly" than what? Are we comparing this to existing subsidiaries or something? What language do they use?

Comment: Assuming a fully affiliated version of the same thing would call itself a "chapter", there's nothing wrong with "semi-independent chapter."

Comment: @Bacon Bits, the existing "chapters" are very strongly connected to the parent organization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are several options along with how I tend to interpret them:

- *semi-autonomous chapter* - "we don't let them boss us around"
- *affiliate* - "we are related, but they don't own us"
- *partner* - "we are independent but work well together"

Comment: I think *affiliate* is particularly apt.

Comment: Yup, I think they're going with affiliate. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This would probably be described as a "loosely affiliated organisation".

Answer (score 0):

Auto-cephalous chapter? Autonomous chapter? Semi-independent chapter?